# Sub Classing UIView Error

Tags: ios, uiview, core-animation

When I set an xib class to a sub class of UIView and then `animateWithDuration` on the UIView I get

```
No visible @interface for 'UIView' declares the selector
'animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:'
```

The error pane shows it is an ARC issue

[image]

I am trying to run an animation on the UIView.

EDIT: The code causing error

```
 [sampleSourceView.view animateWithDuration:1
                                             delay:1.0
                                           options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                                        animations:^{
                                            sampleSourceView.view.frame = sampleSourceFrame;
                                        } 
                                        completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                            NSLog(@"Done!");
                                        }];

        [self.view addSubview:sampleSourceView.view];
```

Comment: Can you post the code that causes the error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are getting the error because you are trying to use a class method on an instance of UIView. Check out the method signature:

```
+ (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration delay:(NSTimeInterval)delay options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options animations:(void (^)(void))animations completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion
```

The plus sign indicates it is a class method. An instance method would have a minus sign.

Try this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1
                     delay:1.0
                   options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                animations:^{
                    sampleSourceView.view.frame = sampleSourceFrame;
                } 
                completion:^(BOOL finished){
                    NSLog(@"Done!");
                }];
```